# Cannot edit pages are migrating wordpress hosting and domain - Error- post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I just migrated a Wordpress website to another hosting and domain.
After migration, I'm not able to update pages. 
Below is the link of the error I get, when I try to update the page.
I have already increased the memory limit to 512MB and the corrupted htaccess file is also renamed.

[image]

Comment: What does the php error log say? Would be good if you can share those lines from logs. 404 for wp-admin/post.php indicates you don’t have same paths after restoration. Can you explain how you migrated Wordpress website?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+F5`. Have you replaced urls in your database entries?

Comment: @ShaunakSontakke -   The url when hit directly opens the edit page, but gives 404 on updating the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have placed your .htaccess file in wp-admin folder? Wordpress requires you to keep that in the root folder which is used to redirect post.php. When you access would-admin url it must be opening, while on submit the htaccess is redirecting.

If this is not the case, please share the contents of your htaccess.

Comment: htaccess file is in the root folder not in wp-admin. below is the content for the same
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Your htaccess looks right. It matches my wordpress .htaccess.

I hope the error log is latest and not an old log line.

The url in the browser console looks like http://example.com/wp-admin, but your log says the url would be http://example.com/Wordpress/ ?
Are you running the site home page to be different from your WordPress installation directory?

Comment: that is an old error log. I have migrated the domain and hosting to godaddy from big host